# Prisma findMany failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, prisma

Recently I updated prisma from 2.7.0 to 2.19.0, I made the respectively changes (findOne to findUnique mainly) but this one refuses to work:

```js
const eventFilter = { AND: [
    { startTime: { lte: moment().toISOString() } },
    { endTime: { gte: moment().toISOString() } },
    { place:{ id: placeId || { not: null } } }
 ] }

await prisma.eventParticipant.findMany({
    where: {
        user: { id: XXX },
        event: eventFilter
    }
})
```

But doing this throws this error (short version hehe):
`` Unknown arg `AND` in where.event.AND for type EventRelationFilter ``

So I looked for the type of `findMany(...)` argument at `index.d.ts` (at node_modules/.prisma/client) and I've found:

```js
findMany<T extends EventParticipantFindManyArgs>(
      args?: SelectSubset<T, EventParticipantFindManyArgs>
    ): CheckSelect<T, PrismaPromise<Array<EventParticipant>>, PrismaPromise<Array<EventParticipantGetPayload<T>>>>
```

Then I looked for what `EventParticipantFindManyArgs` has:

```js
export type EventParticipantFindManyArgs {
    // Has another props but this one is that interest
    where?: EventParticipantWhereInput
}
```

And again ... Looked for what `EventParticipantWhereInput` has:

```js
export type EventParticipatnWhereInput {
    // Like before, this one has another props but this one is that interest
    event?: XOR<EventRelationFilter, EventWhereInput> | null
}
```

At this point i expected that `eventFilter` (my const) fits in `EventParticipatnWhereInput.event` type

And finally I looked for `EventRelationFilter` and it has:

```js
export type EventRelationFilter = {
    is?: EventWhereInput | null
    isNot?: EventWhereInput | null
}
```

Aaand `EventWhereInput` has all props that `eventFilter` has

So ... when i saw it i said: "Why my `eventFilter` object doesn't fit as `EventWhereInput`?"

I've tried to fix this doing:

```js
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client' // Import types from exported namespace called "Prisma"

// This one doesn't throw error like "{...} is not assignable to object of type Prisma.EventWhereInput
// So I assume this is fine
const eventFilter: Prisma.EventWhereInput = { AND: [
    { startTime: { lte: moment().toISOString() } },
    { endTime: { gte: moment().toISOString() } },
    { place:{ id: placeId || { not: null } } }
 ] }
```

But! doing this changes nothing, same error like before (prisma expects where.event to be "EventRelationFilter" type)

So I said "Ok <s>u fking</s> prisma, I'll make `eventFilter` "EventRelationFilter" type:

```js
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client' // Import types from exported namespace called "Prisma"

// This one doesn't throw error like "{...} is not assignable to object of type Prisma.EventRelationFilter
// So I assume this is fine too
const eventFilter: Prisma.EventRelationFilter = { is: { AND: [
    { startTime: { lte: moment().toISOString() } },
    { endTime: { gte: moment().toISOString() } },
    { place:{ id: placeId || { not: null } } }
 ] } }
```

But (and my hopes are gone to stackoverflow from this point) throw this error:
`` Unknown arg `is` in where.event.is for type EventWhereInput ``

And i said: "What?! both are errors? whats does prisma wants from me?"

Sorry, my question is quite long but im very confused about this.

BTW: <s>eventParticipants is the "join table" between user and event</s> I'm not sure

EDIT: Schema:

```
model Event {
  id               Int                @id @default(autoincrement())
  name             String
  description      String?
  // ... 
  participantUsers EventParticipant[]
}


model User {
  id                        Int                    @id @default(autoincrement())
  name                      String
  alias                     String?                @unique @default(dbgenerated())
  birthDay                  DateTime?              @map("dateOfBirth")
  // ...                    
  event                     Event[]
  @@map(name: "user")
}

model EventParticipant {
  id       Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  event_id Int?
  user_id  Int?
  event    Event?   @relation(fields: [event_id], references: [id])
  user     User?    @relation("event_participants_idToUser", fields: [user_id], references: [id])
  @@map(name: "event_participants")
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you share the schema?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my mistake ... `place: { id: { not: null } }` "not" expects to have a `NestedIntFilter` or `number`, so `null` is a invalid value for that key

```js
const eventFilter: Prisma.EventWhereInput = { AND: [
    { startTime: { lte: moment().toISOString() } },
    { endTime: { gte: moment().toISOString() } },
    // WRONG { place:{ id: placeId || { not: null } } }
    { place:{ id: placeId } } // FINE!
 ] }
```

Need to fix that validation in another way .. it's strange the fact that my IDE doesn't throw an error like `{...} is not assignable to Prisma.EventWhereInput`or something like that.